# ContainsKey returns True False

Tags: powershell

Sample data:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
updateresult                   0
updatetime                     1564046484

$newList.ContainsKey("updateresult")
True
False
```

I was wanting to check a key exists before I start working on it, unfornately the containsKey seems to give a result for every line rather then how I would expect contains to work and say True if found at all or false if not found at all.

I thought I could loop the keys and say if true, break. But wonder if there was a better way.

Comment: that works for me - i get ONE returned boolean. ///// what do you get from `$NewList.GetType()`?

Comment: Hmm it does work that way for me:
  
  
    `$newList = @{}  
    $newList.Add("updateresult", 0)  
    $newList.add("updatetime", 1564046484)  
      
    $newList.ContainsKey("updateresult")
    True`
  

What version of PowerShell are you using (`$PSVersionTable`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your `$NewList` is NOT a hashtable ... it is a *collection of hashtables OR dictionary items*. [*grin*] the 2nd item in the collection does not have that key.

here's an example ...

```
$NewList = @(
    @{
        UpdateResult = 0
        UpdateTime = 1564046484
        },
    @{
        ThisAintIt = 666
        }
    )

$NewList.ContainsKey("updateresult")
```

output ...

```
True
False
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess the way I was making the newList was treated as a dictionary or something. I fixed it but putting [String] in my line. So $newList = [string]$malformedList.Split(";") | ConvertFrom-StringData

Comment: @user3520245 - that aint how i would likely have gone at it ... but you need to use what _works_ ... and i am not the one who has his hands on your data. ///// you are most welcome ... glad to have helped a bit! [*grin*]

Comment: I changed it further upstream in the end where I was doing activities around trimming start and end. ConvertFrom-StringData started acting as expected then.

Comment: @user3520245 - ah! input cleaning ... i have spent hours trying to debug stuff that would have been working if i had cleaned the input ... [*sigh ...*]